# Select 2 js adding actions on new option

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I use Select 2 in my form where the option data in it I take from the database and I also add an "add new" button when the searched keyword is not in the database. what I want to ask is, what kind of way can I do to be able to create an action from the button. for example when the button is clicked I can display a text field.

For illustration, here is my code:

```js
$('#add_penilai').select2({
       placeholder: 'Change Name',
       tags : true,
         createTag: function (params) {
    return {
      id: params.term,
      text: params.term,
      newOption: true
    }
  },
   templateResult: function (data) {
    var $result = $("<span></span>");
    $result.text(data.text);
    if (data.newOption) {
      $result.append(`<button type="button"
            class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-10" 
            onClick='Show()'> + Add New Item</button>`);
    }
    return $result;
  },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
            return markup;
        }
    });
```

```css
.form-control.form-control-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control select2" id="add_penilai" name="nama_penilai" onchange="isi_otomatis()" data-width="100%">
     <option value="Jhony">Jhony</option>
     <option value="Kyra">Kyra</option>
     <option value="Ronald">Ronald</option>
 </select>
 
 <input class="form-control form-control-hide" type="text" id="divisi" name="nama_instansi" />
```

Comment: don't get what you exactly want to achive?

Comment: If you want to be able to create new entries in the select why don’t you use the tags option? That’s much easier

Comment: Sorry if my question is too long, actually I just want to create a function on the button in my javascript code. 
LIKE  : 

function show(){
$("#divisi").show();
 }